# I've renewed my SSL certificate... do I need to "do" anything more?

Tags: security-certificate

I've had an SSL certificate for a site for 2 years (from GoDaddy), and it was about to expire in a few weeks.  I renewed with GoDaddy for another 2 years.  Do I need to update anything manually on the server, or does renewing through the SSL provider take care of everything?

Comment: If you don't update the certificate on your server it will show as being expired even if you renewed it at GoDaddy you still must update the certificate on your server.

Answer (score 4):

Unless it is automated, you will almost certainly need to go through the installation process again.

It does seem "convoluted" at first, but it is easier the more you do. However, since you may only do this once a year, I would suggest documenting the steps and putting it in a readme file somewhere on the site. So you can remember the process next year.

Answer (score -2):

If you're just renewing, then I'm assuming you already have the certificate installed on your server. Therefore I doubt you need to do anything more.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case.  My hosting service is having me generate a new certificate signing request (CSR)... which pretty much means I'm going to go through the whole convoluted SSL installation process again.

Answer (score -2):

There is not much difference between buying & renewing SSLs so why not buy SSL certificates from other SSL authorities or SSL resellers where you can find SSLs at a normal price?

Comment: As the certificate was already renewed, this isn't very helpful. Even still it doesn't answer the question asked.

Answer (score -4):

You need to follow the same steps, which you follow during the first time installation.

Please note different SSL Certificate provides same SSL certificate at the different price. You can compare the feature and price before selecting any new SSL.

Comment: This got so many down votes because you included a link and recommendation for a specific SSL provider.  Now that your question has been edited to remove the link, it looks a lot less spammy.